# \changes package: How to accept all changes?

Tags: changes

I am using the `\changes` package to mark out what I have edited in the compiled PDF. Next, is there a way to accept all the changes so that the final PDF only shows the final?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [user manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.pdf), section 4.1.2:

> 4.1.2 final
>
> `\usepackage[final]{changes}`
>
> The final-option disables markup of changes, only the correct text will be shown. The list of changes is disabled, too.
>
> The changes package reuses the declaration of final in `\documentclass`. The local declaration of draftoverrules the declaration of final in `\documentclass`.

Setting the `final` option in either the `usepackage` command for `changes`, or in the `documentclass`, will compile the document with only the corrections shown.